# how do I obtain the confluent Heun equation by taking the confluence limit of the Heun equation?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function

Can anyone please provide me with a mathematical derivation or at least some hints on how to obtain a confluent Heun equation by taking the confluence limit of the Heun equation?

We know that the Heun equation: ${\displaystyle {\frac {d^{2}w}{dz^{2}}}+\left[{\frac {\gamma }{z}}+{\frac {\delta }{z-1}}+{\frac {\epsilon }{z-a}}\right]{\frac {dw}{dz}}+{\frac {\alpha \beta z-q}{z(z-1)(z-a)}}w=0}$, with regular singular points $0$, $1$, $a$, and $\infty$.

And the Confluent Heun eauation:  ${\displaystyle {\frac {d^{2}w}{dz^{2}}}+\left[{\frac {\gamma }{z}}+{\frac {\delta }{z-1}}+\epsilon \right]{\frac {dw}{dz}}+{\frac {\alpha z-q}{z(z-1)}}w=0}$, with regular singular points $0$ and $1$, and irregular singular point at $z = \infty$.

Now my question is: how do I obtain the confluent Heun equation by taking the confluence limit of the Heun equation?